# Help with `call-process-region`: Searching for program: no such file or directory

Tags: process

I have the following snippet:

```
(call-process-region (point-min) (point-max) 
   "python /Users/myname/code/move_imports/moveimports.py")
```

Incredibly, it tells me that it cannot find the file, even though it exists in the very same location given. Same happens with

```
(call-process-region (point-min) (point-max) 
   "/Users/myname/code/move_imports/moveimports.py"))) ; Using shebang in python file
```

How can I fix this problem and run the executable by using the full path?

edit: The error I am getting is `Searching for program: no such file or directory`.

Comment: Try adding `~` before your path, i.e., `~/Users/myname/code/move_imports/moveimports.py`

Comment: Alternatively, visit your python script `moveimports.py` in Emacs, and check the value of `buffer-file-name` with `C-h v buffer-file-name` and use the path that it returns.

Comment: 1st call should be `(call-process-region (point-min) (point-max) "python" nil nil nil "/Users/myname/code/move_imports/moveimports.py")`, can't say why the 2nd should fail, unless the shebang is wrong?

Comment: Does your command work when you run it from a shell? Which file can't it find? *Show us the exact error you're getting.* There is very little information to go on in this question...

Comment: Oh, the subject line has the error. That sounds to me as if the Emacs `exec-path` does not include the directory for the `python` executable (and you have not used an absolute path for that in the shebang line).

Comment: @elethan adding tilde did not help with or without python. Same for adding buffer name like so: `(call-process-region * * "pyt..." nil "buffer_name")`. But thanks, learnt a bit of elisp debugging.

Comment: @npostavs You were correct, thanks. Would you mind adding that as an answer + a simple note about what went wrong? I'll upvote and accept your answer. @phils Thanks for your note about `exec-path`. Other newbs: to allow emacs to use an interpreter/piece of software, add it to the `exec-path` like so: `(add-to-list 'exec-path "/Users/endrebak/Library/Haskell/bin/")` (goes in your `.emacs`/`.spacemacs/config` - whichever applies)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3rd argument to `call-process-region` is an executable file name, not a whole command, so you should call it like this:

```el
(call-process-region
 (point-min) (point-max) "python" nil nil nil
 "/Users/myname/code/move_imports/moveimports.py")
```

This looks for an exectutable named `python` that should be located in one of the directories listed in `exec-path` (you could provide the full path to `python` instead).

The original call would attempt to execute a file called `moveimports.py` under a subdirectory named `python /Users/myname/code/move_imports/`.

---

You may find it easier to use `shell-command-on-region` which would work with your first form:

```el
(shell-command-on-region
 (point-min) (point-max) 
 "python /Users/myname/code/move_imports/moveimports.py")
```

You do have to watch out for spaces in file names and other shell meta-characters in this case though.  Also note that the shell uses the environment variable `PATH` which usually (but not necessarily) contains the same list (encoded to a `:` separated string) as `exec-path` (especially Mac users should consider using [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell)).

---

I believe the second form

```el
(call-process-region (point-min) (point-max) 
   "/Users/myname/code/move_imports/moveimports.py"))) ; Using shebang in python file
```

should work unless `"/Users/myname/code/move_imports/moveimports.py"` is not marked executable, or its shebang is incorrect.

Comment: I read that an interactive function like `shell-command-on-region` should preferably avoided in elisp code (no reason was given?)

Comment: @TheUnfunCat: no, *certain* interactive functions should be avoided in elisp code (usually because they cause visible UI effects), but many (most?) interactive functions can be used non-interactively as well. You may want to avoid `shell-command-on-region` because of the complications using a shell brings (e.g. meta-characters in file names).